# Benefit of using CreateProxy<UserAccount>() vs new UserAccount()

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core with Lazy Loading Proxies, I have a UserAccount Model which has a property "LocalizationId" and a Lazy Load Navigation Property "Localization".

What benefit is there to using DatabaseContext.CreateProxy<UserAccount>() vs new UserAccount()?

In both cases, once the model is added to the DatabaseContext, and the Id of the Navigation property is set, the Navigation Property is Lazy Loaded and changes are tracked as expected...

```
var model = new Models.UserAccount()
{
  LocalizationId = 1
};
DatabaseContext.Add(model);
var proxy = DatabaseContext.CreateProxy<Models.UserAccount>();
DatabaseContext.Add(proxy);
proxy.LocalizationId = 1;

var proxyLocalization = proxy.Localization.Name;
var modelLocalization = model.Localization.Name;
```

I feel like I have to be missing something obvious, because I don't see the benefit to using CreateProxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference that object created by `CreateProxy` can load related entity later instead of.

You have the same result in both objects because `var proxyLocalization = proxy.Localization.Name` have loaded Localization object and added to change tracker. Change tracker have found your non-proxied object and initialized automatically related property.

Comment: If I remove the code associated with the proxy object and run SQL Profiler, the Localization is properly lazy loaded only when the property is accessed. It appears to behave the same as the proxy object, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: If Localization class with Id == 1 already in Change Tracker, It will be assigned automatically. Create clean tests with different ids. It is not possible technically to load Localization via `model.Localization.Name` it should throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: Apologies, UseLazyLoadingProxies was enabled, but the model is also implemented using the ILazyLoader, which explains why this works without using CreateProxy... <facepalm> sorry for wasting your time.